# minimize method not taking argument

Tags: python, tensorflow

From the tensorflow doc i have read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/AdamOptimizer), I have tried to minimise the adam optimizer.

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer
print("Using AdamOptimizer...")

train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step = global_step,var_list = [process_image])
```

But I receive this error below from the code. Even though I have passed through the 'loss' argument. I think it may be due to using Tensorflow 2?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a loss tensor called loss?
In that case, you could try to write simply :

```
optimizer.minimize(loss = loss, ...)
```